# Setting up Git/Bitbucket on a Server: Permission Issues

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but I'm still scratching my head after over an hour of debugging. I had set up Git using HTTPS earlier, but I'd like to use SSH now. However, when I `git pull origin master`, I get

```
error: git checkout-index: unable to create file test.txt (Permission denied)
```

I believe it's because the files are owned by `apache` and I need to configure something for Git to write to the files owned by apache.

Here are some info. `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` gives:

```
logged in as my_bitbucket_username.
```

`ll ~/.ssh/` gives:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 username 4.0K May 20 00:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 username 4.0K May 19 23:41 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 username  410 May 18 18:13 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 username   51 May 20 00:19 config
-rw------- 1 username  132 May 19 23:54 environment
-rw------- 1 username 1.8K May 20 00:18 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 username  414 May 20 00:18 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 username  410 May 19 23:45 known_hosts
```

`sudo .git/config` gives:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:bitbucket_user/myrepo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

`ssh-add -l` gives:

```
2048 ... /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

This is the set up right now.

1. Web application files/directories are owned by `apache`
2. `.git` directory is <s>owned by root</s> also owned by apache
3. I log in as `username` and home is `/home/username`. I have sudo.
4. I have my key at `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

What I want is the ability to log in as `username` and pull and push to the repo using this key. How do I configure this so that I or another user can `git push/pull` without messing file ownership in this web app directory?

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't use `sudo`: `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` uses your current user account. `sudo` uses `/root`.

Or, if you have to use `sudo`, make sure `/root/.ssh` contains the public/private ssh key used to access bitbucket a sudo ssh session should fail.

Comment: I've updated my post a little. I got the push to work, but the pull doesn't work. I think I know the reason, but I don't know how to solve it. I haven't tried `sudo git pull...` because I wasn't sure how that would change the file ownership, which is `apache`.

Comment: @musicliftsme why could you not use `git pull` directly? Without `sudo`? And with the right account?

Comment: I'm unable to use `git pull` as myself (`username`) because I don't have permission to `apache`'s directory and files. I even added myself to the `apache` group, but it denies me access. I don't want to `sudo git pull` because then it will change files to be owned by `root`.

Comment: Strange, I can now pull and get new files from the repo. It seems that my only issue now is getting these new files to be owned by apache. Sounds like I have to use a deployment script or something to change the owner back to `apache` after deployment?